# Having trouble using count

Tags: php

```
    foreach ($studentData['questions'] as $questionId => $questionData) {



        echo '<h3>'.$questionData['questionno'].': '.$questionData['content'].'</h3>';

}
```

The code above could display 3 questions for example:

1. What is 2+2?
2. What is 3+3?
3. What is 4+4?

Now what I want to do is perform a count to determine how many questions there are so I did the code below:

```
    foreach ($studentData['questions'] as $questionId => $questionData) {

$noofquestions = count($questionData['questionno']);

        echo '<h3>'.$questionData['questionno'].': '.$questionData['content'].'</h3>';

}
```

But the problem is that instead of outputting `3` for `$noofquestions` it is outputting `1`. Why is this?

Also I want to perform a count on how may times `Fully Correct` is displayed as `$noofcorrect` and seperately how many times `Not Correct / Not Fully Correct` appears but not sure how to determine this with code of this being below:

```
    <?php

    if($check)
{
    echo '<p class="green"><strong>Fully Correct</strong></p>';
}
else
{
    echo '<p class="red"><strong>Not Correct / Not Fully Correct</strong></p>';
}
```

Comment: Re-check all your variable names. Re-read the foreach syntax documentation. We can see $studentData has three items in it but you are counting $questionData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the following

```
$count=0;
foreach ($studentData['questions'] as $questionId => $questionData) 
{

    $count += 1;

    echo '<h3>'.$questionData['questionno'].': '.$questionData['content'].'</h3>';

}

echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `count` on the string that is the question number. Why does it surprise you that it doesn't return the count of the array?

Put `$noofquestions = count($studentData['questions']);` before the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Ok, can I ask about how to find number of correct and incorrect questions, it is displaing both as 1 when it should be 2 incorrect and 1 correct out of the three questions